# Ordering changes to descending when where clause is specified

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django 1.6.5 application with models representing images related via ForeignKey to models representing rental types. Each rental type has 5 related images.  The image models inherit from an abstract model.

```
class PropertyImage(models.Model):

    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path,
                               processors=[ResizeToFit(609, 456)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60},
                               verbose_name = _("Image"))

   class Meta:
      abstract = True


class LongLetImage(PrpertyImage):
   property = models.ForeignKey(LongLet, related_name='images')
```

For reason I cannot understand one of the related image models are returned in descending order when accessed via the related field  i.e. longlet1.images.all(). This is happening at the database layer as when I try:

```
select * from longletimage where property_id=X;
```

the images are returned from the highest ID to the lowest. However when I try:

```
select * from longletimage;
```

the images are returned correctly in ascending order (from the row with the lowest ID to the highest) - as expected.

This is only happening for one out of 7 models and only in the production database. In my dev and staging databases (hosted on separate hosts) images are returned in the default sort order (ascending).

The database is PostgreSQL 9.3.

Why is the order different when where clause is specified and how do I change it? Why would this happen for only one model if they are all the same?

EDIT:

Per Daniel's comment I had to specify the default ordering on the model. This can be done using Meta class as per Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#model-meta-options)

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['id']
```

Comment: The premise is wrong if you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. Without it, no particular order is to be expected. Per the manual: _If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce._ (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

Comment: that was it. I can't accept the comment as the answer. I guess you can remove the comment and add an answer if you want me to accept it. I have edited my question to include the Django level solution. Cheers